# Docker Compose - [link/mount volume/volume_from] sharing data between containers, not using host

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, docker-compose

Sorry I'm not sure of the correct terminology ( So I'll try to get my point across by using it all). Sorry still new to docker.

I need a way to  [link/mount volume/volume_from] storage between containers - but cant seem to figure it out. I don't want to use the host machine as I'm trying to share access to a large s3 bucket - i.e. host machine physically can't store a copy of it all.

### docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  hostname: web
  image:  mprasil/webdav
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - s3
  volumes:
    - /local/dir/:/site/input/

s3:
  image: xueshanf/s3fs
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `--volumes-from` you can use.

```
$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
You can then use the --volumes-from flag to mount the /dbdata volume in another container.

$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db1 training/postgres
And another:

$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db2 training/postgres
In this case, if the postgres image contained a directory called /dbdata then mounting the volumes from the dbdata container hides the /dbdata files from the postgres image. The result is only the files from the dbdata container are visible.

You can use multiple --volumes-from parameters to bring together multiple data volumes from multiple containers.
```

So in your case, you can update `docker-compose.yaml` in container `web`:

```
volumes_from:
 - s3
```

refer: 
[Managing data in containers: Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

[docker-compose.yml reference: volumes_from](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/)

Comment: thanks @BMW, question how would you access the data, from the web container? where would it be located?